# My copy of VS 2013 express does not come with TypeScript

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

So the TypeScript website says that Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 comes with TypeScript. I have Visual Studio 2013 Express and I don't have any project templates for TypeScript, when I add a file I don't see a TypeScript file either. I installed the command line compiler and the 2012 project templates but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you downloaded VS 2013 Express for Desktop?
Typescript support should be present in VS 2013 Express for Web which you can find here: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#DownloadFamilies_2

Comment: I have the web version, desktop, and windows 8.